# repaint on the JFrames when the input arrives

Tags: java, swing, awt

Currently i am working on DEVSJAVA models and trying to make a GUI for those models.
In the below code i have written a **displayphase** class.In this class whenever a new input arrives it goes into the **delext function** and then reads the value of the varaible "result" and call the **showstate function** and then it should paint the result on the JFrame and again when another input arrives it should repaint on the JFrame.

But in the code what i have written makes all the panels print on the JFrame rather than repainting it. I know the error is in adding new panel everytime it goes into the showstate function. But i am unable to make it work.Could please help me out from this error.

```
            package assignment2;

import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

import simView.*;


import genDevs.modeling.*;
import genDevs.simulation.*;
import GenCol.*;
import simView.*;

public class displayphase extends ViewableAtomic{//ViewableAtomic is used instead
                                //of atomic due to its
                                //graphics capability
protected entity job;
protected double cul,cll,hul,hll,temp,varout,output,a,b,c,d,g;
protected double processing_time,temperature,temp1,temp2;
protected boolean acStatus,heaterStatus;
protected String result;
**JFrame f=new JFrame();**

public displayphase(){
this("displayphase" 
    );
}

public displayphase(String  name){
super(name);
addInport("in");
addOutport("out");
addInport("in1"); 
addOutport("out1");
addOutport("out2");
addOutport("out3");
addRealTestInput("in1",71);
addRealTestInput("in",75);
addTestInput("in",new job("job","coolair",72.5),1);
addTestInput("in",new job("job",true,false,60),0);
addRealTestInput("in",3,1);
// processing_time = Processing_time;

}

 public void initialize(){
 phase = "passive";
 sigma = INFINITY;
 a=0;b=0;c=0;d=0;g=0;
 job = new entity("job");
 super.initialize();

 }


 public void  deltext(double e,message   x)
 {
Continue(e);

if (phaseIs("passive"))

    for (int i=0; i< x.getLength();i++)
          if (somethingOnPort(x,"in"))
              {  job dummy;
              entity ent = x.getValOnPort("in",i);
             // doubleEnt tem = (doubleEnt) job;
              dummy = (job) ent;
              temp= dummy.getthetemperature();
               result = dummy.getthestate();
               heaterStatus = dummy.isHeaterStatus();
               System.out.println("The phase in ac"+result);
      temperature = temp;
      holdIn("busy",processing_time);
      }

if (phaseIs("passive"))

    for (int i=0; i< x.getLength();i++)
          if (somethingOnPort(x,"in1"))
              {  job dummy;
              entity ent = x.getValOnPort("in1",i);
             // doubleEnt tem = (doubleEnt) job;
              dummy = (job) ent;
              temp= dummy.getthetemperature();
               result = dummy.getthestate();
               System.out.println("The phase in heater"+result);
               heaterStatus = dummy.isHeaterStatus();
      temperature=temp;
      holdIn("busy",processing_time);
      }


 **showstate()**;

      }




   public void  deltint( )
  {
   passivate();

   }

  public void deltcon(double e,message x)
  {
  /*deltint();
   deltext(20,x);
  */}


  public message  out( )
  {
  return outputNameOnPort(result,"out");
   }

   **public void showstate(){


       f.add(new MyPanel());
       f.repaint();
       f.pack();
       f.setVisible(true);

    }

  class MyPanel extends JPanel {
        public MyPanel() {
            setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
        }
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(250,200);
        }
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);       
            String ac,ab;

  if(result == "aboveHT" || result=="coolAir")
      ac = "cooler on";
  else
      ac = "cooler off";

 /* else if(result == "belowHT" || result == "passive" || result=="belowH")
      ac = "cooler off";*/

  if(result == "belowHt" )
      ab = "Heater on";

  else
      ab="Heater off";

 //String ac=String.valueOf(timesacon());
 // JFrame f=new JFrame();


  JLabel l=new JLabel("THE STATUS OF AC IS ",JLabel.CENTER);

  JLabel p=new JLabel("THE STATUS OF HEATER IS",JLabel.CENTER);
 /* p.setVerticalTextPosition(JLabel.BOTTOM);
  p.setHorizontalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);*/
  JTextField t=new  JTextField("");
  t.setSize(80, 40);
  t.setText(ac);
  Point p1=new Point(100, 100);
  t.setLocation(100,100);
  l.setLocation(80, 80);

  JTextField v=new JTextField("");
  v.setSize(80,40);
  v.setText(ab);
  Point p2=new Point(100,200);
  v.setLocation(p2);
  p.setLocation(80, 180);
  this.add(l);
  this.add(p);
  this.add(t);
  this.add(v);
  this.setSize(500, 300);
 // f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
//  f.pack();
 this.setVisible(true);

    }
    }
      }**
```

Comment: `"But in the code what i have written makes all the panels print on the JFrame rather than repainting it."` -- this statement confuses me. If you don't get a good answer soon, please consider clarifying your problem description for us.

Comment: Also, please consider formatting your code so that your indentations are consistent and make sense, and get rid of those `**` present in the code as they're distracting to us and get in the way of the code formatting. Thanks.

Comment: And regarding, `if(result == "aboveHT" || result=="coolAir")` -- never use `==` to compare Strings. Use `equals(...)` or `equalsIgnoreCase(...)`.

Comment: Finally (I think) -- your problem and code appear fairly complex, and much depends on code and classes that are unavailable to us, making it difficult for us to answer. If you don't get a solution soon, consider creating and posting an [sscce](http://sscce.org), a small program that compiles and runs, that attempts to reproduce your problem, that requires no outside dependencies or classes, and that we can test and modify.

Comment: Do you really want to add another pane when ever the state changes?  Wouldn't it be better to simply update the state of the existing panel?  Don't add (or even modify the state of any) components within any `paintXxx` method, this is not what painting is for!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not modify that state of any component from within any `paintXxx` method.  This will trigger a cascade of `repaint` events, which will continue to be called until you CPU is running hot and you program is unresponsive...

The `paintXxx` methods are used to provide the ability to perform custom painting of a component, not modify its state.

Instead, construct the basic UI in the constructor and provide some means by which the state of the fields can be changed, for example, via a `updateState` method...

```
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;


class MyPanel extends JPanel {

    private JTextField t;
    private JTextField v;

    public MyPanel() {
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));

        JLabel l = new JLabel("THE STATUS OF AC IS ", JLabel.CENTER);

        JLabel p = new JLabel("THE STATUS OF HEATER IS", JLabel.CENTER);

        t = new JTextField("");
        v = new JTextField("");
        this.add(l);
        this.add(p);
        this.add(t);
        this.add(v);

    }

    public void updateState(String result) {

        String ac, ab;

        if ("aboveHT".equals(result) || "coolAir".equals(result)) {
            ac = "cooler on";
        } else {
            ac = "cooler off";
        }

        if ("belowHt".equals(result)) {
            ab = "Heater on";
        } else {
            ab = "Heater off";
        }

        t.setText(ac);
        v.setText(ab);

    }        
}
```

`String` comparison in Java is done via the `String#equals` method.  Using `==` is simply comparing the object memory reference, which has a very low likelihood of ever being `true`

Without knowing more, I would create an instance of a `JFrame`, add `MyPanel` to it and simply call `MyPanel#updateState` when you need to change it's state.

Modern UI's are expected to be capable of running on a variety of platforms, even when running the same OS, there are differences in the way that fonts may be rendered, making any statically placed and sized components unusable.  Instead you should make use of the layout manager API which has being designed to solve this problem with minimal work on your part.

See [Laying out components within a container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)

Comment: @user2872321 Well, that makes a nice change ;)